# Route Host traffic through VirtualBox Guest

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I would like to know if it is possible to redirect the internet traffic of my computer through a host virtual machine using it as a VPN. So far I only found ways to pass from Guest to Host.

It's a matter of company policy making the official VPN available on Windows only, but for obvious reasons I'd prefer to stay on Linux.